# Cocoapods: how to create a pod using the latest Swift version?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am learning how to create a pod using Cocoapods, so I ran this command:

```
pod lib create {my_pod_name}
```

Using iOS platform, Swift language, including a demo application in my library, and not using any testing framework nor view based testing.

However, when opening the project, I'm getting the warning:

> Conversion to Swift 4.2 is available

That's what I see in the build settings:

[image]

So why is this happening?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show your podspec. If you haven't done that already, add the line `s.swift_version = '4.2'` to it (assuming `s` is your spec)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was more like: what is actually deciding when I first create a pod that the default Swift version if 4.0 ?

Comment: What's your current cocoapod version? I think the current cocoapod create a Xcode 9 project instead of Xcode 10, so that's why it's using Swift 4.0 by default (see here: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/upgrading-to-swift-4.2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the Swift version is dictated by the [Podspec](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html).

In more details, it would look like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  ...
  spec.swift_version = '4.2'
  ...
end
```

I assume that if this is left out, that it currently defaults to 4.0.

If you want to go more into detail, check the [source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/lib/cocoapods/target/pod_target.rb):

```
# @return [String] the Swift version for the target. If the pod author has provided a set of Swift versions
#         supported by their pod then the max Swift version across all of target definitions is chosen, unless
#         a target definition specifies explicit requirements for supported Swift versions. Otherwise the Swift
#         version is derived by the target definitions that integrate this pod as long as they are the same.
#
def swift_version
  @swift_version ||= begin
    if spec_swift_versions.empty?
      target_definitions.map(&:swift_version).compact.uniq.first
    else
      spec_swift_versions.sort.reverse_each.find do |swift_version|
        target_definitions.all? do |td|
          td.supports_swift_version?(swift_version)
        end
      end.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, I understand that I can select the `swift_version` by specifying it into the `podspec`, but what I want to know is what decides that the default `swift_version` is 4.0 if not specified in the `podspec` ?

Comment: You can check the version implementation in the source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/lib/cocoapods/target/pod_target.rb